# Convert Class Instance to float

Tags: php, type-conversion, operator-overloading

Lets say there is this class:

```
class Number {
  private $asString;
  private $asFloat;

  public function __construct($input) {
    $this->asString = $input;
    $this->asFloat = $this->parse($input);
  }

  private function parse($input) {…}

  //magic method for $n1 . $n2 operations
  public function __toString() { … }

  //method for $n1 + $n2 operations
  public function __toFloat() { … }
}
```

Unfortunately the `__toFloat()` magic method does not exist. Is there any way, other than: `$sum = $n1->toFloat() + $n2->toFloat()`, without having to call that `->toFloat()` method all the time, when the object is used in the context of mathematical operations.

In Javascript on has the ability to create a `valueOf()` method and I am searching for a way to create something similar in php. Any ideas?

Comment: I would love php to have operator overloading, but it never seems to be mentioned.

Comment: You could use `__invoke()`, it is called when a script tries to call an object as a function. This would make your example: `$sum = $n1() + $n2()`. Which is quite short. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke I would not do this, because it can be confusing for whoever will read your code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That looks like a good Idea

Comment: Yes just invoke

Comment: Like a lot of php code - hacks make neat tricks but code which is like reading alchemy.  Say it in the wrong way and your data vanishes in a puff of smoke.

Comment: @NigelRen You are absolutely right! I would prefer to have proper operator overloading as well. To figure the best, probably minimum »hackish« way, I posed t that question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `invoke` as solution for this case

```
<?php
class Number
{
  private $asString;
  private $asFloat;

  public function __construct($input)
  {
    $this->asString = $input;
    $this->asFloat  = $this->parse($input);
  }

  public function __invoke()
  {
    return $this->asFloat;
  }

  private function parse($input)
  {
    return (float) $input;
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->asString;
  }
}

$n1 = new Number(5);
$n2 = new Number(3);
var_dump($n1() + $n2());
```